# Splitting the first word from each record and push that in to array

Tags: bash

inputfile : records.txt

```
100,Surender,CTS
101,Kumar,TCS
102,Raja,CTS
103,Vijay,TCS
```

I want to store the first column from each record and store that in to array .

I wrote the below script

```
id_array=();
while read  -a my_line ;

do

  id_array+=(${my_line[0]})

  done < /home/user/surender/linux/inputfiles/records.txt;

 echo ${id_array[0]}
 echo ${id_array[1]}
 echo ${id_array[2]}
 echo ${id_array[3]}
```

My expected output is

```
100
101
102
103
```

But as Per above code i get the below output

```
 100,Surender,CTS
 101,Kumar,TCS
 102,Raja,CTS
 103,Vijay,TCS
```

I dont know where to specify the respective delimiter(comma) in above  script.

Need some Help on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods to get the first field. Cut is very intuitive, although this is probably not the most efficient code:

```
id_array+=(echo $my_line | cut -d ',' -f 1)
```

explanation:

- `-d ','` : delimiter is `,`
- `-f 1` : take the first field

in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918931/2082964) you can find a more efficient way, setting the internal field separator (IFS) to `,`...

Comment: Yes. This Helps.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Replace the line:

```
while read  -a my_line ;
```

With:

```
while IFS=',' read  -a my_line ;
```

That will split the lines into an array using the delimiter `,`.